# How can I send message to actor from different class?

Tags: scala, akka

I have two classes with different ActorSystem with their corresponding actors. How can actor from class1 send message to actor in class2?

Comment: Are they in the same JVM or different JVMs?

Answer (score 5):

Why do you have 2 `ActorSystem`s? Unless you have a really good reason, you should create all your actors in the same `ActorSystem`. Creating an `ActorSystem` is very expensive and communication as well as error handling are harder. Here's a simple example of communication between actors:

```
class Foo extends Actor {

  val barActor = context.actorFor("/user/bar")

  def receive = {
    case 'Send => barActor ! "message from foo!"
  }
}

class Bar extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case x => println("Got " + x)
  }
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val system = ActorSystem("MySystem")
    val foo = system.actorOf(Props[Foo], "foo")
    val bar = system.actorOf(Props[Bar], "bar")

    foo ! 'Send
  }
}
```

With `system.actorFor` or `context.actorFor`, you can retrieve an `ActorRef` for a given path. The path for user created actors always starts with `/user` and includes all parent actors. So if you have a hierarchy of 3 actors the path could be `/user/actorA/actorB/actorC`.

Comment: Also, if there really needs to be 2 ActorSystems, Akka Remoting is how you connect them.

Comment: Do you mean that's the preferred solution, or that's the only way it will work? (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

See the [docs on Actor Paths](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/general/addressing.html).   The actor path includes the actor system.

So for example if your actor systems are named `system1` and `system2`, and both of your actors are top level actors named `actor1` and `actor2`, you can get `ActorRefs` for them like:

```
// inside actor1
val actor2 = system.actorFor("akka://system2/user/actor2")
actor2 ! "Foo"
```

and

```
// inside actor2
val actor1 = system.actorFor("akka://system1/user/actor1")
actor1 ! "bar"
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not really sure what are you asking about.

If the actor class is `MyClass` and the message object is `Message`, you just do

```
val myInstance = new MyClass()
myInstance ! Message
```

And that's it. You can call that from within any other actor.